# Highcharts full width issue in Lightning Salesforce1 app after locker service is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, locker-service, highcharts

I am having problem to set the highcharts to complete width of the parent div container in Salesforce1 Lightning app when locker service is enabled.
I haven't given any specific width in the highcharts configuration, but only to the parent div comprising the highcharts.
But the highcharts is not being rendered as full width of the container.

```
<div aura:id="chart" class="chart" style="height:100%;width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When LockerService is enabled, do you see everything rendered, including all labels?

I'm looking at an issue where vertical axis labels are missing. If you could post sample code or even screenshots with/without LockerService enabled, it would be of tremendous help.

Comment: Hi @jf-paradis ,
I've also faced similar issue.
When locker service is enabled, an additional "<rect>" tag with classname "highcharts-background" is coming. So, for the time being, I handled this particular issue by giving style "fill-opacity: 0;". After applying this, you'll be able to see the labels. :)
Also, when locker is disabled, the above mentioned tag is not coming.
Is this an issue with the locker service? (For new orgs, since locker is activated by default, it's very difficult to handle many things using JavaScript.)

Do you have any workarounds for these sort of issues?

Comment: I don't have a workaround at this point. But stay tuned, we're on it!

And many thanks for the extra information.

Comment: Oh ok. As I told before, I'm having issues in accessing DOM elements (of the same component only) too in afterRender (To calculate height, I use documentElement.clientHeight; because window.outerHeight; has issues in devices.. But when locker is enabled, this doesn't work as expected.)..
Hope there'll be a clearer idea/way on things like these very soon. 
Thank you @jf-paradis.